# react-native style iframe to fit webview

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, webview

I'm trying to implement various `embed` in a react-native application;

They have these structures

**Twitter**

```
<blockquote class=\"twitter-tweet\" data-width=\"500\"><p lang=\"en\" dir=\"ltr\">i recorded my calc professor for an entire semester, I hope he never sees this but... GOOOD MORNINGGGG <a href=\"">pic.twitter.com/lTXGcd1Jf0</a></p>— Edward Chai (@edwardchaii) <a href=\"https://twitter.com/edwardchaii/status/1020733530362425344?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw\">July 21, 2018</a></blockquote>\n<script async src=\"https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js\" charset=\"utf-8\"></script>\n
```

**Spotify**

```
<iframe src=\"https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/2dgrYdgguVZKeCsrVb9XEs%3Fsi%3DQ7ihpJ__RCSHIgTzf1_QBA\" width=\"300\" height=\"380\" frameborder=\"0\" allowtransparency=\"true\" allow=\"encrypted-media\"></iframe>
```

Using `react-native-webview` [module](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview) and this structure in my `Component`

```
    <View style={{flex: 1, height: 300, width: 350, marginVertical: 10, position: "relative"}}>
    <WebView
      originWhitelist={["*"]}
      style={{width: "100%"}}
      onLoad={this.onLoad}
      onLoadEnd={this.onLoad}
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
      // useWebKit={false}
      injectedJavascript={this.state.injectedJavaScript}
      source={{html: this.state.html}}
      startInLoadingState={true}
    />
  </View>
```

The result is (on iOS simulator)

[image: embed in ios simulator]

As you can see there are a couple of problems:

1. Since the container `View` must have a `width` and a `height` value it does not respect the `embed` size; sometimes it's taller sometimes it's smaller sometimes it's wider
2. The `embed` doesn't fit its container; I tried to put `width: 100%` but even if it fits the `width` I still have the container `height` fixed which leaves a lot of blank space.

I don't know where to put my hands, I tried a lot of hacky solution but it doesn't seem to work at all

Comment: did you get the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using [scalepagetofit](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview#scalespagetofit) property ?, it should match the view

Comment: the default value is true

Comment: but the problem is that when `useWebKit={false}` the webview doesn't even load

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2023**
now have an easy option to display tweets, pass a URL (in your case use the id) with the package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-twitter-preview

and usage:

```
<TwitterPreview
  url={'https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1020733530362425344'}
/>
```