# Opening I frame in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stripe-payments

I'm  integrating stripe payment in react-native and wants to open an iframe with specific url from after buttton click.

Scenario : user will enter the card details, details will be given to api end point and it will return an url that will contain the authentication part like OTP. So I want that url to be opened how to do so ? Let me if is there any better way to open that authentication middleware.

Adding code below

```
Payment.js


import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';
import stripe from 'tipsi-stripe';
import { doPayment } from '../api/api';
import { Auth } from './Auth';

stripe.setOptions({
  publishableKey: 'pk_test_********',
});

export default class Payment extends Component {
  state = {
    isPaymentPending: false
  }
  requestPayment = () => {
    this.setState({ isPaymentPending: true });
    return stripe
      .paymentRequestWithCardForm()
      .then(stripeTokenInfo => {
        return doPayment(10330, stripeTokenInfo.tokenId);
      })
      .then((res) => {
        let url = "<iFrame src='" + res.intent_url + "' />"
        console.log(res, url);
        openAuthentication(url);  --->>>> here i'm calling a function with url
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.warn('Payment failed', { error });
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({ isPaymentPending: false });
      });
  };



  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button
          title="Make a payment"
          onPress={this.requestPayment}
          disabled={this.state.isPaymentPending}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

openAuthentication = (url) => {
  console.log("Here with props :::::::", url);
 // here I want to open an iframe, i'm getting correct url, I've checked it in a static html page and it is working
  <Auth url={url} />
}

const styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
};



Auth.js



import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  View, StyleSheet
} from 'react-native'
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview'

export default class Auth extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    console.log(props, ">>>>>>>>>>>")
  }
  render() {
    console.log("In Auth -----------");
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <WebView
          source={{ uri: 'myUrl' }}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  }
})
```

Error:

> React.createElement type is invalid, expected a string or a class/function.

Comment: Have you tried displaying the iFrame inside a WebView?

Comment: I'm not able to open up my Auth page. 
I've added code for the same. I've logged some print statements but it's not working. I've added error in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Auth` needs to be returned by a `render` function, otherwise nothing will show up.

So, you'll want something similar to this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button
                title="Make a payment"
                onPress={this.requestPayment}
                disabled={this.state.isPaymentPending}
            />

            {this.state.url && (
                <Auth url={this.state.url} />
            )}
        </View>
    );
}
```

You only want to render auth when you have the url.

For this, you want to update your state to look something like this:

```
state = {
    isPaymentPending: false,
    url: undefined
}
```

And

```
.then((res) => {
    let url = "<iFrame src='" + res.intent_url + "' />";
    this.setState({ url });
})
```

In order to update you state with the received url when the promise resolves. This will update your state, set the url, and re-render. Because you have an url, `Auth` should be rendered as well.

LE:

Your `Auth.js` should look something like this in order to be able to display static HTML. `this.props.url` should be valid HTML.

```
render() {
    console.log("In Auth -----------");
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <WebView
                source={{ html: this.props.url }}
                originWhitelist={['*']}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Your answer works, i'm getting url in my Auth screen but unable to open iframe in webview? can you please help me with this

Comment: Updated the answer. You can first try to display some dummy html string instead of the iFrame to make sure it works, and replace it with your iFrame afterwards.

Comment: I followed this question and it works. thanks btw. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54025762/react-native-style-iframe-to-fit-webview